# How to efficiently browse and compare the values of a very large dictionary with the elements of a list?

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dictionary, geopandas

I have a dictionary (list_image_dict) and a list (structures.geometry), I want to compare each value in the dictionary with the values in the list, perform a quick operation on it and replace the value in the dictionary.

But `list_image_dict` contains 300623 key/value pairs, going through all values and comparing them with each element of `structures.geometry` is very long. Several tens of minutes. My question is **how to improve the speed of execution?**

I tried by multiprocessing with 16 cores on simply `list_image` list. Each elements of the list are compared in parallel with the elements of structures.geometry, it's a little bit faster but still very slow (still several tens of minutes). `structures.geometry` contains only 156 elements.

```py
def make_sort(layers, structures, threshold):
    def coverage(a, b): return a.area/b.area*100
    def label(
        polygon): return structures.loc[structures.geometry == polygon, "label"].values[0]
    frames = pd.concat([*layers], ignore_index=True)
    frames.crs = "epsg:3857"
    frames = frames.to_crs(epsg=4326)
    main = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=frames.geometry)

    list_image = main.geometry.tolist() 
    #list_image has 300623 elements. 
    list_image_dict = {images.wkt: images for images in list_image}
    
    for key, value in list_image_dict.items(): #main loop on list_image_dict
        liste=[]
        for item in structures.geometry: #structures has 156 elements.
            if value.intersects(item):
                x = value.intersection(item)
                #for a certain threshold coverage (in percent) present on the image
                #the polygon is added to the liste. 
                if coverage(x, item) >= threshold:
                    liste.append([x, str(label(item))])
        list_image_dict[key] = liste
    return list_image_dict
```

With the help of people in comments, this way leads to some minutes less but it is still very long.

```py
def make_sort(layers, structures, threshold):
    def coverage(a, b): return a.area/b.area*100

    label = structures["label"].to_list()
    geom = structures["geometry"].to_list()
    
    frames = pd.concat([*layers], ignore_index=True)
    frames.crs = "epsg:3857"
    frames = frames.to_crs(epsg=4326)
    main = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=frames.geometry)
    
    final = []
    for elem in main.geometry:
        liste=[]
        for item in structures.geometry:
            if coverage(elem.intersection(item), item) >= threshold:
                liste.append([elem.intersection(item), label[geom.index(item)]])

        final.append({elem.wkt: liste})

    result = dict(ChainMap(*final))
    return result
```

Comment: I don't think the bottleneck is on iterating over the values of the dictionary

Comment: Where do you think it is located ? at the label function call maybe ? To find the label (name) of each polygon.

Comment: It seems like ```if value.intersects(item):``` and ```x = value.intersection(item)``` could be redundant and slowing things down. Would ```x = value.intersection(item)``` and ```if x:``` work with whatever type ```value``` is?

Comment: One way by which you could _slightly_ improve the performance is by not converting the `GeoDataFrame` object (i.e., `main`) to a list type. You could instead use `main.geometry.iterrows()` which returns an iterator. This way it would neither take up too much space nor will hurt the performance due to conversion of the DataFrame to list entirely.

Comment: It can be as simple as `if coverage(value.intersection(item), item) >= threshold`

Comment: What are the values of the list_image_dict?

Comment: Values of list_image_dict and structures.geometry are both polygons

Comment: Would this help https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.intersection.html?

Comment: Yes I was thinking about this method, but I need to compare each polygon in list_image with every polygon in structures, not by index or matching order.

Comment: if you post some reproducible example I (and others) might help you much better

Comment: Can an item match on more than one item in the list? If not, you can break out of the loop after the match. And if this is the case, you could also put the most common items at the start of the list.

Comment: Yes, an element of `structures` can match with several elements of `main`. How to know which elements of main are the most common? The problem is that these can vary.

Comment: @dankal444 I would like but it's tricky as these are very large geojson files.. and you need them to be reproductible.

Comment: @Tim instead of posting those geojson files, maybe make some generator of fake data that is similar enough? I know its easy to say though

Comment: Tim, use R-Tree to solve your problem. See my answer below but my solution could be more precise with samples as suggested by @dankal444.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, now, you have 2 GeoDataFrames: `main` (300623 polygons) and `structures` (156 polygons). First you want to find intersection then select only polygons which the coverage is greater than `threshold`. The bottleneck is to find the intersection of one polygon from `structures` to the 300K polygons of `main`.

I think the better solution is to use **Spatial Index** and **R-Tree**. For that, you need to install `PyGeos` to access to `main.sindex`.

To quickly find which polygons intersect to another:

```
for idx, item in structures.iterrows():
    print(item['label'])

    # All polygons...
    indexes = main.sindex.query(item['geometry'], predicate='intersects')
    # ...greater than or equal to threshold
    indexes = main.iloc[indexes, main.columns.get_loc('geometry')] \
                 .apply(coverage, b=item['geometry']).ge(threshold) \
                 .loc[lambda x: x].index
    # Do stuff here
    ...
```

Comment: Now you have your 6 polygons from `main` that intersect with the current polygon of `structures`, what do you want to do now? It's a bit unclear for me what you expect. (I slightly modified my answer to get current label of the current polygon).

Comment: Do you run this code over your data? Is it more faster than before?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand directly, it is indeed very fast! (at least really faster than my other method). I'll come back to you very quickly to validate the answer if everything is correct on the result.

Comment: It's work fine and really faster. Thanks! You can also maybe prefer itertuples() to iterrows() which is generally faster.

Comment: In case where indexes return an empty [] I have `TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'GeometryArray' and 'int'`. What is the best way to make sure this is not the case, sorting indexes before main.iloc? I added `if indexes.size != 0:`. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: There is nothing you can do better than the `if ...` If the polygon does not intersect any other, you have to deal with this case. I don't think it impacts the runtime.